# Hide timespan function after three days in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have created a listing service that shows a timespan of when the post was published. However, I want to hide this feature when the post is more than 3 days old.

This is my code

```
<div class="listing-time"><?php echo timespan($data->time); ?> since</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How looks like `$data->time`?

Comment: PHP time()-function, saved in a database. @Tpojka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ( time() - $data->time < 259200 ):?>
<div class="listing-time"><?php echo timespan($data->time); ?> since</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I am glad you made it.